# Why do we need a mutex lock when adding a number?

Tags: thread-safety, mutex, atomic

I know the operation of adding a number is an instruction. And It shouldn’t be interrupted. So why isn't adding an atomic operation? Why we need a mutex lock?

Comment: The issue would not be the addition itself, but rather the read and update of the memory location.

Comment: @npinti “add dst src” The same dst can do that

Comment: I'd say that depends on the memory model, language abstraction and processor, etc.. You probably should be more precise in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
void add(int *dst, int src)
{
    *dst += src;
}
```

On ARM64 in compiles to:

```
ldr w2, [x0]
add w1, w2, w1
str w1, [x0]
ret
```

ARM64 does not have "add" instruction that operates on memory, only on registers, so addition has to be implemented using 3 instructions: load, add,  store.

On x86-64 it compiles to:

```
add DWORD PTR [rdi], esi
ret
```

So it is a single instruction, but to execute it Intel cpu will split this instruction internally into 3 microinstructions of the internal execution engine: load-add-store. So there is no difference between the two architectures.

Additionally, cpus use [write buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_buffer) to improve performance of memory operations. The last store will be buffered, so the actually write to the memory is delayed and there is plenty of time for other cpus to modify the value.

If you need to do addition atomically, processors provide some way of performing simple operations atomically, so mutex is not needed.

Intel has `lock` prefix so you can do `lock add`. ARM64 since ARMv8.1 has `STADD`, before that a combination of `ldxr` and `stxr` can be used.